# Should I make SOAP logout call

Tags: soap-api, login

I'm concerning about [logout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm) SOAP call. What's the purpose of making this call? I believe, any call to API is counted towards the API call limit, so this call just closes the session (session will be closed anyway by timeout) but that costs 1 API call. Are there any benefits for closing the Salesforce session by calling logout? I'm using login/password authentication.

Comment: Ensures that any replay activity e.g. a user leaves their computer unattended and a malicious user goes back in the browser history and tries to modify some data is blocked. (As you are talking about an API maybe there are other closed sessions that would block that.) I agree that many users abandon sessions, but if they've gone to the trouble of logging out I'd say the app should do its best to make use of that event too.